# ServiceStack CookieException

Tags: c#, api, servicestack

Under ServiceStack (3.9.33) we are getting the following exception:

```
errorCode":"CookieException"
"message":"The 'Name'='$Version' part of the cookie is invalid."
"stackTrace":"   at System.Net.Cookie..ctor(String name, String value)\r\n   at
System.Net.Cookie..ctor(String name, String value, String path, String domain)\r\n   at
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpRequestWrapper.get_Cookies()\r\n   at
ServiceStack.ServiceHost.HttpRequestAuthentication.GetCookieValue(IHttpRequest httpReq, 
String cookieName)\r\n   at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.AuthenticateAttribute.AuthenticateIfDigestAuth(IHttpRequest 
req, IHttpResponse res)\r\n   at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.AuthenticateAttribute.Execute(IHttpRequest req, 
IHttpResponse res, Object requestDto)\r\n   at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.RequestFilterAttribute.RequestFilter(IHttpRequest req, 
IHttpResponse res, Object requestDto)\r\n   at 
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.EndpointHost.ApplyRequestFilters(IHttpRequest httpReq, 
IHttpResponse httpRes, Object requestDto)\r\n   at 
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, 
IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName)
```

When our vendor (code we do not control) submits the following request:

```
Content-Length: 283401
Authorization: Basic --------------------------
Cookie: $Version=0; ss-id=----; $Path=/, $Version=0; ss-pid=---; $Path=/
Host: -----
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
```

Any possible work-arounds or settings we could use to avoid the exception?

Thanks.

Comment: I would first upgrade to the latest version of ServiceStack which at this time is v3.9.38, if it's still an issue send a reproducible failing test to the [ServiceStack project's GitHub issues](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/).

Answer (score 1):

I just got a bunch of the same errors in my log today (ServiceStack 3.9.67).

I wouldn't worry about trying to avoid the exceptions or return the normal resource. I'm no PHP developer but I believe they are maliciously formed requests - the attacker is expecting a PHP server. They are either attempting to probe for the PHP version and environment working directory, or trying to set the environment variable to the root directory (I'm not sure on the direction of the 'cookie <-> variable' crap-magic that PHP does).

EDIT: I ended up writing a fix for it: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/857